# Select multiple elements per row in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

With

```
ad = np.array([ 0.5,  0.8,  0.9,  0.1])
cp = np.array([[2,3,1,1,2,0],[1,0,1,3,1,2],[1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,2,3,2,2]])
```

How can I get Numpy to give me the elements of `ad` with the indexes of `cp[0,:]` as first row (the indexes are `[2,3,1,1,2,0]` so the first row should be `[0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5]`), the elements with the indexes of `cp[1,:]` as second row etc.?

So the result should be:

```
[[0.9, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.5],
 [0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.8, 0.9],
 [0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8],
 [0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 0.9]]
```

Preferably, of course, in an efficient and elegant way.

Comment: ..... `ad[cp]`?

Comment: Nice :D I feel so incredibly stupid right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays support broadcasting. It will broadcast `ad` to the needed shape. So this

```
>>> ad[cp]
array([[ 0.9,  0.1,  0.8,  0.8,  0.9,  0.5],
       [ 0.8,  0.5,  0.8,  0.1,  0.8,  0.9],
       [ 0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8],
       [ 0.5,  0.8,  0.9,  0.1,  0.9,  0.9]])
```

will work.

Alternatively, you can use `np.take()`:

```
>>> np.take(ad, cp)
array([[ 0.9,  0.1,  0.8,  0.8,  0.9,  0.5],
       [ 0.8,  0.5,  0.8,  0.1,  0.8,  0.9],
       [ 0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8,  0.8],
       [ 0.5,  0.8,  0.9,  0.1,  0.9,  0.9]])
```